# How can I get 'edge' points (furthest edge coordinates) from a list of coordinates

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am new to mapbox and not so experienced with working with maps and I am trying to draw a polygon from a list of coordinates that I have. So far this is the code I have;

```
const accessToken = <myTokenHere>;
const center = [36.813288, -1.2813976];
const mycords = [
 [36.88888, -1.3008283333333335 ],
 [ 36.88977666666666,-1.30097 ],
 [36.88977666666666, -1.30097],
 [36.88977666666666, -1.30097 ],
 //...
];
mapboxgl.accessToken = accessToken;
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center,
    zoom: 7
});
map.on('load', () => {
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'vendors',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'Polygon',
                'coordinates': [mycords]
            }
        }
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#181A4A',
        'fill-opacity': 0.6
    }
  }); 
});
```

The above code draws a polygon as depicted below. [image: how the above code draws the polygon]

My intention is to draw a polygon like the one below based off my coordinates;[image: What I intend to draw]

I think I need to get the "edges" so that I can be able to pass those coordinates to the layer. My question is how do I achieve this? I have checked [mapboxes API documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/) but I haven't managed to come across a method that does this.

Comment: Where do you get your `twigaVendorCords`

Comment: edited to the question. mycords const contains a long list of about 1700 pairs of lat and lng's kept it brief but ideally that is how it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, Mapbox GL doesn't provide many data processing tools. For that, we recommend using [Turf](http://turfjs.org/). It's difficult for me to tell exactly what you've got and what you're trying to do but it looks like one of the following methods may be what you're looking for:

- http://turfjs.org/Docs#polygonize
- http://turfjs.org/Docs#concave
- http://turfjs.org/Docs#convex

Comment: My goal is to avoid the polygon drawing the coordinates inside of outermost edges. Not sure if you get what I mean. The polygon should only draw the outermost coordinates like in the first screenshot as opposed to the second one.

Comment: @JoeNg'ethe that sounds like you want to use http://turfjs.org/Docs/#concave as Lucas mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas I ended up using https://github.com/mapbox/concaveman for this. Pretty straightforward I passed by coordinates to the concaveman method and then used that to draw the polygon. Cheers.